# RasterVector conversion in IDRISI selva

Tags: land-cover, terrset

I am using Idrisi selva for converting road network map in raster but it always shows "Vector raster window do not overlap". I have checked coordinate system for every related vector and raster file.

How can I convert vector file to raster in IDRISI selva?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to create an initial blank file in which to display the vector image onto. To do this you go to Data entry- Initial, then you create the blank with the output file being "Roads_blank" and file to copy parameters from being your mask land cover file (file of your country landcover)-the blank should be an Integer file. After the initial blank is created, you have to do a vector to raster conversion. This you can do in Reformat- RastertoVector. In here you have to select the vector to raster option, and then Line to raster. Your input image will be your road network vector file, while the image to be updated will be the blank you just created in the previous step. Press ok, and the road network rasterized file should appear. Make sure that you check the metadata of the newly created raster file, it should be in a byte binary format.